# How to put text on top of a pattern overlay CSS

Tags: html, css

Might be an easy one can't get this to work. I've succeded in overlay a background image with a pattern but now the header is placed behind the pattern as well. I've tried to use z-index (as depicted in my code below) but it still not working. Any ideas?

**Result**

[image]

**Index.html**

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="subheader">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>PROVIDE <br>CREATIVITY IN <br> YOUR BUSINESS</h1>
          </div>
         <div class="pixel-overlay"></div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

**Style.css**

```
.content .subheader {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 130px 0 0;
    background: url(../images/landing.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0%;
    position: relative;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -ms-behavior: url(../js/backgroundsize.htc);
}

.content .subheader:after {
    content: "";
    background: url(../images/pattern/pattern.png) repeat;
    background-size: 90%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    opacity: 0.2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}

.content .subheader h1 {
    margin-top: 25%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: can you add in jsfiddle and show this up for testing?

Comment: You need to position your h1 like `position:relative` or `position:absolute` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.content .subheader h1` have no `position` specified. Therefore, `z-index` will be useless. 
Try adding `position: relative`:

```
.content .subheader h1 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try add `position: relative;` to the headline, like this:

```
.content .subheader h1 {
    margin-top: 25%;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}
```